# vim - update file history more often

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I was wondering if it is at all possible to have vim update its file history more often.

For example, if I got into insert mode, and type 20 lines of code, exit, and hit 'u', it undoes everything I had typed in.

Is there a way to make make these undos more granular without needing to pop in and out of insert mode all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly create an additional undo point via `<C-G>u` in insert mode (`:help i_CTRL-G_u`).

Because that is tedious, I would recommend to build mappings that trigger this. For example, when completing a sentence:

```
inoremap . <C-g>u.
```

Or when inserting a register:

```
inoremap <C-r> <C-g>u<C-r>
```

You can also create one when pausing briefly, through an `:autocmd`:

```
autocmd CursorHoldI * call feedkeys("\<C-g>u", 'n')
```

Comment: What do you mean by inserting a register? Also,  what does the n in the last command stand for?

Comment: You can paste from insert mode via `<C-r>{register}`, like `"{register}p` in normal mode. Since that can add a whole lot of text, an undo point is helpful.

Comment: You can use the excellent `:help` to answer further questions: `:help feedkeys()` tells you that `n` means _do not remap keys_.